# Changing layout -how can I style this differently?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some JSON data which is rendering absolutely fine.

Currently I'm getting the name, price, image (see screenshot) from my object which is super.

[image]

However, I need to style this to make each of the dresses look like this but horizontally (screen shot)
[image]

Now I managed to style the image to make it 300px using a style tag in the JS, however, I am clueless as to how I'm going to style the rest of the elements? Do i use a normal stylesheet?

**Here is my HTML**- as you can see, i've just got one div with the id jsonData that's holding all of the data.

```
<body>
  <h1>IF YOU LIKE THIS, YOU MIGHT INTERESTED IN THESE</h1>
  <div id="jsonData"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
    <div id="jsonData">
    </div>
</body>
```

**Here is my JS**

```
var obj = {
  'placements': [
    {
      'id': '029148',
      'name': 'Woodblock Play Suit',
      'linkURL':'http://www.warehouse.co.uk/gb/just-arrived/all/woodblock-play-suit/029148.html',
      'imageURL':'http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aaxe_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-WAREHOUSE/default/dw0f93fcd4/images/hi-res/warehouse_02914899_2.jpg',
      'price':'46.00'
    },
    {
      'id':'0294526806',
      'name':'Smock Dress',
      'linkURL':'http://www.warehouse.co.uk/gb/just-arrived/all/smock-dress/0294526806.html',
      'imageURL':'http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aaxe_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-WAREHOUSE/default/dwc9d5ea05/images/hi-res/warehouse_02945268_5.jpg',
      'price':'39.00'
    },
    {
      'id':'0297180006',
      'name':'Cami',
      'linkURL':'http://www.warehouse.co.uk/gb/just-arrived/all/cami/0297180006.html',
      'imageURL':'http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aaxe_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-WAREHOUSE/default/dw4b954022/images/hi-res/warehouse_02971800_2.jpg',
      'price':'9.00'
    },
    {
      'id':'0298473606',
      'name':'Asymmetric Wrap Cami Dress',
      'linkURL':'http://www.warehouse.co.uk/gb/just-arrived/all/asymmetric-wrap-cami-dress/0298473606.html',
      'imageURL':'http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aaxe_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-WAREHOUSE/default/dw686fea84/images/hi-res/warehouse_02984736_2.jpg',
      'price':'46.00'
    },
    {
      'id':'0297155306',
      'name':'Casual Stripe Tee',
      'linkURL':'http://www.warehouse.co.uk/gb/just-arrived/all/casual-stripe-tee/0297155306.html',
      'imageURL':'http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aaxe_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-WAREHOUSE/default/dw4609af3e/images/hi-res/warehouse_02971553_2.jpg',
      'price':'16.00'
    }
  ]
};

var divId = document.getElementById('jsonData');
for(var i=0;i<obj.placements.length;i++) {
  divId.innerHTML += '' + obj.placements[i]['name'];
  divId.innerHTML += '<br>';
  divId.innerHTML += '' + obj.placements[i]['price'];
  divId.innerHTML += '<br>';
  divId.innerHTML += '<img src="' + obj.placements[i]['imageURL'] + '" style="max-width: 300px" /><br />';
}
```

Sorry if this is mega simple, I'm new to rendering JSON.

Comment: You are outputting HTML, not JSON. Style it with CSS like any other HTML.

Comment: Split the task up. Figure out the HTML you want to generate. Figure out what CSS you need to get the layout you want. Then worry about generating the HTML from JS.

Comment: "I'm new to rendering JSON". This has nothing to do with rendering JSON. Browsers don't render JSON. They render markup languages. For someone who "completed an intense three month Web Development course", I would think they might have taught you that basic concept.

Comment: @nattie87 — How about *not putting all the data into one div*? As I said, figure out the right HTML then generate that HTML.

Comment: You would need to structure the HTML output with some additional elements eg. `divId.innerHTML += '<div class="myClass:">' + obj.placements[i]['name'] + '</div>';`

Answer (score 2):

Make adjustments to your code in something like this

```
var divId = document.getElementById('jsonData');
for(var i=0;i<obj.placements.length;i++) {
  divId.innerHTML += '<div class="block"><span class="name">' + obj.placements[i]['name'];
  divId.innerHTML += '</span>';
  divId.innerHTML += '<span class="price">' + obj.placements[i]['price'];
  divId.innerHTML += '</span>';
  divId.innerHTML += '<img class="image" src="' + obj.placements[i]['imageURL'] + '" style="max-width: 300px" /></div>';
}
```

after that you will get your output in format like this

```
<div class="block">
  <span class="name">OutputName</span>
  <span class="price">OutputPrice</span>
  <img class="image" src="OutputImage">
</div>
```

Later its easy to make adjustments visually by applying css/less/sass.

here is less example on how to align boxes floating left with width of 300px;

```
.block {
  widht: 300px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;

  .price {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that adding a LESS example without a plain CSS example is just confusing matters.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the following steps:

1. First, you need to have the data in a javascript object, so you could access it conveniently (use JSON.parse to get the object from a JSON string).
2. Then, you can set up a template of the HTML, write the relevant tags and prepare them to hold the data.
3. As a final step, in the method that receives the data (for example, the success callback of an ajax call to the server), update the data in the relevant html tags using javascript.
4. Please note that this far we discussed placing the data in the HTML. The styling itself will be done via CSS, as you would do with regular static data. Please make sure you assign relevant ids / classes to the divs that hold the data, so you could refer to them in the CSS. For example, .name class for the product name div, etc.

Comment: The data is in an object `var obj = {}`

Comment: Tried to write a full answer - if it's already an object, you can skip #1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Well friend! Don't use javascript for styling just add specific `class` attributes to your `img` tags or more conviently wrap your `img` tags inside `div` according to your need and apply classes to these `divs`. Then you can style using CSS any way you want.

**Example:**

```
var divId = document.getElementById('jsonData');
for(var i=0;i<obj.placements.length;i++) {
  divId.innerHTML += '' + obj.placements[i]['name'];
  divId.innerHTML += '<br>';
  divId.innerHTML += '' + obj.placements[i]['price'];
  divId.innerHTML += '<br>';
  divId.innerHTML += '<img src="' + obj.placements[i]['imageURL'] + '" class='myImage'" /><br />';
}
```

Then add CSS in separate files:

```
.myImage {
 width: 300px;
}
//and for selecting any specific element use
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
    color: black;
}
```

> **Note:** It is also a best practice to separate your design from logic and markup. You can achieve any style in CSS these days.